# how to set background on ListView

Tags: android, listview, background, set

i wanna set my listview's background like in the link's pic, it should be shown as button but i cant set background separately.

http://www.delta.edu/images/OIT/Android%20List%20View.png

i've tried `android:listSelector="@drawable/pic"` and this didnt work for me.

i tried `tools:listitem="@layout/row"` too, but it didnt worked for me.

I hope i was clear about my problem.

Comment: You have to set the background on the xml of your adapter's xml

Comment: You need to set the background for the row (if you are talking about setting button/card-like background as in the pic). In that case, just alter the row xml to have a background.

Comment: Do you wanna set one common Background for all of your app or only a specific one for the ListView ?

Comment: @Srikanth yes i wanna set background for the row. 
I couldnt do that, i created a xml for that but its doenst worked

Comment: Since it is a complex layout, you will be using an adapter other than an ArrayAdapter. In the getView() method of the adapter, you will be inflating the row xml. The layout (container) of the xml should have the android:background="so-&-so" property set. Test that out with a simple color first. It works. If it is still not happening, post your code with xml.

Answer (score 0):

Check out a [tutorial like this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-background-row-style-rounded-corner-alternate-color.html) for some hints.

Create an XML file in drawable similar to this:

**rounded_corners.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#00FF00"/>

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <padding android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" />

    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#00CC00"/>
</shape>
```

**listview_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner" android:state_enabled="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner" android:state_pressed="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rounded_corner" android:state_focused="true"/>

</selector>
```

Apply it to the ListView Adapter similar to this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    PlanetHolder holder = new PlanetHolder();

    // First let's verify the convertView is not null
    if (convertView == null) {
        // This a new view we inflate the new layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);

        holder.planetNameView = tv;

        v.setTag(holder);

        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
    }
    else 
        holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();

    Planet p = planetList.get(position);
    holder.planetNameView.setText(p.getName());

    return v;
}
```